# How to execute an operator on the result of a linq subquery only when the result is not null?

Tags: c#, linq

I will simplify my linq query to this:

```
var q = (from x in ...
select new 
{
 CustomDate = (from t in ....
                select new 
                {t.CreatedDate}).Max(cd=>cd.CreatedDate)
})
```

The problem is Max blows up if the result of the sub query is null. How to assign a nullable date when the sub query is empty and assign a Max date when there's data from the subquery? (making CustomDate a string and return a string for the date is an option too)

Comment: I don't understand what `select new {t.CreatedDate}` does. It seems to be creating an anonymous type, but there's no property name to which `t.CreatedDate` is being assigned.

Comment: Could you post the entire query?

Comment: @Asad: if no property name is given, it's simply taken from the name of the property in the expression. I.e. `CreatedDate` becomes the property name in the anonymous type.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Didn't know that, thanks! That brings up the question of why the OP is creating an anonymous type with only one property in it.

Comment: @Asad: I'm assuming that the example is just for illustration purposes. It's plausible that in the real code, there are multiple properties, and that this is just the problematic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Enumerable.Max()` method will return `null` if `TSource` is a reference type (or, as it happens, a `Nullable<T>` type) and the source is empty. So one possible option would be something like this:

```
let maxDate = (from t in ...
              select new { t.CreatedDate }).Max(cd => (DateTime?)cd.CreatedDate)
select new
{
    CustomDate = maxDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue
}
```

Note that if you don't want `CustomDate` to be `Nullable<DateTime>`, you can of course cast back to the desired type after the null has been coalesced.